# Python - Add string to beginning of file in loop

Tags: python, file-io

I have this code:

```
read = open('file.py', 'r+')

intent = 0

for line in read:
    if '{' in line:
        intent += 1
        #print intent, ", up"
    if '}' in line:
        #intent -= 1
        print intent, ", down"
    if "    " in line:
        print "tab"
```

I want to add

```
"\t" * intent
```

to the beginning every line.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question body doesn't match your title. How is this writing to lines "by index"?

Comment: Why are you reading `file.py` file as text?

Answer (score 0):

You can open, read, edit, then overwrite the file to acheive this effect, as follows:

```
file=open('file.py', 'r')
lines=file.read().split('\n')
file.close()
output=[('\t'*intent)+i for i in lines]
file=open('file.py', 'w')
file.writelines(output)
file.close()
```

Comment: @AviBag if an answer solves your problem, you can press the green tick on it. It means that future people with your problem can see the answer more easily, as well as awarding you 2rep and the answerer 15rep.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
read = open('file.py', 'r+')

indent = 0
new_lines = []

for line in read:
    new_lines.append(("\t" * indent) + line)
    if '{' in line:
        indent += 1
    if '}' in line:
        indent -= 1

print("".join(new_lines))
```